# How to get data of sublist in suitelet using request getparameter?

Tags: netsuite

```
    var form = nlapiCreateForm("Process Order Items");  
    var locField = form.addField('custpage_locationlist', 'select', 'Location', 'location').setMandatory(true);
    if(locationId != '')
    locField.setDefaultValue(locationId);

    var vendorField = form.addField('custpage_vendorlist', 'select', 'Vendor', 'vendor').setMandatory(true);
    if(vendorId != '')
    vendorField.setDefaultValue(vendorId);

    form.addField('custpage_incitemnoprefvendor', 'checkbox', 'Include Items With No Preferred Vendor');
    form.addField('custpage_incitemvendornopref', 'checkbox', 'Include Items Where Vendor is Not Preferred').setDisplayType('disabled');
    var parentField = form.addField('custpage_parentitems', 'select', 'Parent Item', 'inventoryitem');
    if(parentId != '')
    parentField.setDefaultValue(parentId);

    form.addField('custpage_minimunqty', 'integer', 'Minimum Quantity');
    form.addField('custpage_tobeprinted', 'checkbox', 'To Be Printed');
    form.addField('custpage_tobemailed', 'checkbox', 'To Be Mailed');
    form.addField('custpage_tobefaxed', 'checkbox', 'To Be Faxed');
    form.addField('custpage_total', 'float', 'Total').setDisplayType('inline');

    var sublist = form.addSubList("custpage_orditemslist", 'list', 'Order Items'); //staticlist
    sublist.addField('custpage_selectitem','checkbox', 'Select');
    sublist.addField('custpage_location','select','Location','location');//.setDisplayType('inline');
    sublist.addField('custpage_department','select','Department','department').setDisplayType('inline')
    sublist.addField('custpage_class','select', 'Class','classification').setDisplayType('inline');
    sublist.addField('custpage_itemid','select','Item','inventoryitem').setDisplayType('inline');
```

I am able to get the data of location and vendor like this

```
request.getParameter('custpage_locationlist')
request.getParameter('custpage_vendorlist')
```

but my question is, how to get the data of sublist in else part of the suitlet

```
if (request.getMethod() == 'GET' )
       {

}
else{

}
```

form is being created in if part but how to get data of sublist in request.getParameter, in else part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do `request.getLineItemCount('custpage_orditemslist')` and `request.getLineItemValue('custpage_orditemslist','custpage_selectitem',x)`.

Comment: what if I wanna take the getLineItemText ?? 
for example (SS2.0): context.request.getSublistText({group:'', name:'', line:''}); 
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Have not tried this but according to SuiteAnswers ID: 510221 - "By prepending 'inpt_' to the id of the select field, Users can retrieve the text value of the selected option of a select field in the POST request processing of the Suitelet."

Comment: Hi Rusty, Thank you so much for your answer. I have tried that solution, but it doesn't work with sublist fields values, it only works with select values.However, I eventually, run another search of selected transaction and get the text values.Again, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
request.getParameter('custpage_orditemslistdata');
```