# How to get lineitemvalues in suitelet

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

i have to create a suitelet page where at first should get all the vendors based on the date range entered and then has to get the the details of the resulted vendors selected(there is a  checkbox column through which i can select the vendors) after the submit button is clicked.
But here i am not able to get the sublist values to the sublist api getlineitemvalue of the selected vendors

```
var sub =request.getParameter('custpage_transaction_list');
    var count =  sublist.getLineItemCount()
```

//request.getLineItemCount('custpage_transaction_list');
        nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "sublist", count);
        // This variable will keep track of how many records are selected.
        var num = 0;

```
    //for each line in the sublist
    for (var i = 1; i < count + 1; i++) {
        //get the value of the Delete checkbox
        //var linenum =  nlapiSelectLineItem('custpage_transaction_list',i);
        var itemvalue = sublist.getLineItemValue(
            'custpage_transaction_list',
            'internalid',
            i
        );
        nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "not_yet", itemvalue);
        // If it's checked, get the transaction
        if (itemvalue == 'T') {
            nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "get", itemvalue);
            // Get the transaction internal ID
            var internalId = nlapiGetLineItemValue(
                'custpage_transaction_list',
                'internalid',
                i
            );
```

Comment: I think this is related to this question. [Get values of Suitelet sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542148/how-to-get-data-of-sublist-in-suitelet-using-request-getparameter/40543785#40543785)

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the record first and then do record.getLineItemValue

Comment: The sublist is on custom form and i have tried nlobjsublist.getLineItemValue but no improvement

Comment: I have never seen code like this before. I wonder if it works in the first place. For example, you are using sublist.getLineItemCount() but you are not specifying the sublist. It usually works like record.getLineItemCount('item').  To get the item sublist